# Explore whether the following integral converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

$$ \int_{-1}^0 \frac{\sqrt[5]{1-e^x}}{\sqrt[3]{x-\sin(x)}} dx$$

I'm trying to find whether the following integral converges or diverges. I plugged it into wolfram alpha and got the answer that the integral diverges. And I also found that it diverges if we expand $e^x$ as $1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} $ and $\sin(x)$ as $x-\frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}$ but anything less on both and it converges. I'm trying to understand why and also find out what is the correct way to solve this question.

Comment: Hint: Let $f(x)$ be your integrand, and take $g(x)=-\frac{1}{x^{4/5}}$. Then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\longrightarrow 6^{1/3}$ as $x\longrightarrow 0^{-}$

Comment: Why did you divide by g(x) and how does this show that the integral diverges or converges?

Comment: Have you heard of the limit comparison test before? It only applies to positive integrands, but a slight modification of your integrand will make it positive and suitable for such a comparison.

Comment: Ah now it makes sense thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand $e^x=1+x+..$ and $sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+...$ to get integrand ~ $x=0$ as $I\approx \frac{\sqrt[5]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x^3/6}}\approx cx^{-4/5}$.  Therefore integral converges.